# HTTP Status 404 - Servlet DispatcherServlet is not available

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, servlets, web.xml

When i am trying to run the application on server it is showing DispatcherServlet is not available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Why it is showing Dispatcher servlet is not available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add init-param tag specifying the location of dispatcher servlet xml file location.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>DispatcherServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/DispatcherServlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```